# Guzzle 5.3 Passing GET array parameters not working

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 5.3, and looks like it is changing my array parameters, removing indexes.

This is my request:

```
$request = $client->createRequest(
    'GET',
    'http://myserver.com/file.php?param=1&arrayparam[10]=2015&arrayparam[18]=2016'
);
$response = $client->send($request);
```

Using the Subscriber\History, the Request is going:

> GET /file.php?param=1&**arrayparam=2015&arrayparam=2016** HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: myserver.com

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Searching on github issues, I found that you can use different aggregate methods. So I changed my code to use phpAggregator():

```
$request = $client->createRequest(
    'GET',
    'http://myserver.com/file.php?param=1&arrayparam[10]=2015&arrayparam[18]=2016'
);
$request->getQuery()->setAggregator(Query::phpAggregator());
$response = $client->send($request);
```

Hope it helps!